# Setting MACs setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on Amazon Linux

Tags: ssh, security, amazon-linux

We are going through the process of hardening Amazon Linux 1 based on [CIS](https://www.cisecurity.org).

Control 5.2.12 states under "Expected Values" :

> The following List String value(s) **X** indicate the current
>   status of the **MACs** setting defined within the
>   **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** file.
>
> ======Expected Value(s)======
>   contains regular expression list
>   hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com
>   umac-128-etm@openssh.com
>   hmac-sha2-512 hmac-sha2-256
>   umac-128@openssh.com
>   curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
>   diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256

Based on [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/420283) RHEL documentation of the setting, we appended the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```

`/etc/init.d/sshd restart` results in the following error:

> Starting sshd: /etc/ssh/sshd_config line 142: Bad SSH2 Mac spec
>   'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256'. [FAILED]

How do we configure SSHD MACs on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log entry indicates that your version of OpenSSH didn't recognize one or more of the MAC algorithms you specified.

Given that it's Amazon Linux, I would guess it's going to be anything related to curve25519. Otherwise, you can try adding them one at a time until it fails to start again, then you will know which is the cause.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. By progressively testing, I found that `curve25519-sha256@libssh.org` and `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` had to be removed. The Amazon Linux version is 4.14.47-56.37.amzn1.x86_64

Comment: That's pretty unfortunate. I suggest moving to Amazon Linux 2 if you can. Or another more reasonable Linux distro.